Trading permanent magic items between player's own characters in AL in 2024
I was wondering what the current Adventurers League rules were governing the trading of permanent magic items between a player's own characters.
FYI I am asking this in May of 2024 which means that the most recent "D&D Adventurers League Player's Guide" is Version 14.0 with an effective date of March 4, 2024.
The Version 14 guide states:

Permanent magic items can be traded (see below). Unique magic items
may not be traded.
Trading permanent magic items with other characters in your
character’s campaign is on a one-for-one basis of equivalent rarity.
Certificates (if present) must also be traded or destroyed. You cannot
trade with characters attached to a campaign world other than the one
you’ve chosen for your character.
Whenever you trade a magic item, you spend 5 downtime days.

Since this text makes no reference to the player who actually owns the character, I assume that players are allowed to trade permanent (non-unique) magic items between their own characters as long as they are in the same campaign-world and at the same level of rarity.
I'd appreciate if the community could confirm if my understanding of this is correct with regards to Adventurers League rules in effect as of May 2024.
Thanks all :)

You can trade between your characters in the same campaign
You cited from the latest iteration of the AL rules. The important part is:

Trading permanent magic items with other characters in your character’s campaign is on a one-for-one basis of equivalent rarity

The only restrictions on trading are:

The items are not unique or player created
The items must be permanent items
The characters that trade spend 5 downtime days each
You can only trade on a one-for-one basis
The items you trade are of the same rarity
Both characters must be played in the same campaign (and consequently, on the same campaign world)

If all these are fullfilled, and you have two characters that you play in the same campaign, you can trade items between them. There is no other rules update or restriction that has been announced for this, not in the official Player or DM guide, and also not on the Adventurer's League discord.
